# OSMdroid and ESPG 3395 projection

Tags: android, dictionary, openstreetmap, osmdroid

I need to use different cards in the application. I use osmdroid. It works perfectly with most maps. But there is a map, the tiles of which do not coincide with the location. The fact is that this map uses a different projection of the tiles. Its standard is ESPG 3395.
Projects such as OpeneLayers have the ability to change the projection, but I did not find it in osmdroid. As far as I understand, it is necessary to redefine the method of OnDraw in TilesOverlay. In this method, self-tamper (?) Tiles and redraw.
Any ideas? Or solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You'll be in for a quite a bit of work to change the projection with osmdroid. See the Projection and TileSystem classes. Those are the primary classes that you would need to update. And everything related to tile loading, since osm's z/x/y format won't apply anymore (or will it?)

Comment: I am not sure that it will be a bit of work. I think I need  download and rescale and redraw tiles. And yes, format is x/y/z